# How to connect two inputs to one output for a mains connection

Tags: power, switches, mains

[image]

I have a digital switching system in my home that controls the water heaters. One heater is shared between two rooms and I need a connection such that it can be turned on from either room.

I'm looking for something like an OR gate that will work for mains rated 250V/5A. What can I effectively place in the blank space to physically achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible that what you actually want is a two-way switch, not an OR implementation. It's probably a good idea for you to google "two-way switch", and confirm if that is what you're after, or if OR functionality is really what you want.

Comment: I do in fact want OR functionality. The person in each room should be able to turn the geyser on independently of the other. With a two-way switch there would be too much confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYLpzI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Typical 2-way switching as used on stairways. (b) OR switching.*

- If you want either room to be able to switch on or off then use (a).
- If you want the heater to be on if either or both rooms require it then use (b).

If you want to switch the input to the digital system then:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSoAFj.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Switching an input for a digital controller.*

Comment: Option b is exactly what I'm going for. I'm unsure of how to physically achieve that. I have two inputs that will come from the switch of each room and need to pass that into a single output for the heater. What device can I use to do this?

Comment: Option b of Figure 1 or 2? Why are you looking for a device? I thought you had one.

Comment: I've edited the question to add an image. I have the switching system but can't directly short the two lines coming from the switched and connect it to the heater right?

Comment: So you want Figure 1b? Just connect the two switch wire at the heater terminal.

Comment: Alright thank you! I was worried that might cause an issue of some kind if both switches were on.

Comment: As long as both switches are fed from the same circuit breaker it's OK.